# Calling a function on duplicating

Tags: python

I am wondering if it is possible to call a Python function inside a Blender when an object with a name that starts with `foo_` gets duplicated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are probably looking for this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19669/7777 You just need to watch the number of objects inside a scene with this watcher.

Comment: I saw that answer, it would work, but i am new in python, so as I understand all i need to change is `add_watcher()` line, but how to watch the change in number of objects in scene?