# Custom default settings for nodes/materials

Tags: materials, node-editor, customization

Is it possible  to set custom default values for nodes? For example, if I add a math node I would like it to be set to multiply by default.

In a similar trend, is it possible to have the Principled BSDF as the default shader when creating a new material?

Thanks.

Edit: the "duplicate question" provides only a rough workaround to one part of my question, so I don't quite regard it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default shader to principled brdf](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97796/how-to-set-default-shader-to-principled-brdf)

Comment: You could always make a "default" material, set it's fake user flag and store it in your startup scene. So changing to your default material will be trivial, even if it's not fully automatic.

Comment: That might be not possible at least from GUI. If you script material adding then you define what is there but you will get predefined nodes first and then do something with them if needed (remove/create new ones), related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/add-nodes-to-material-with-python and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python