# How can I set default values for the Principled BSDF shader?

Tags: materials, node-editor, customization

It's pretty simple, I just want to be able to make it so when I add a Principled BDSF Shader, that the "Base Color" (or any other value for that matter) is always set to pure white, opposed to off-white by default.

When you right click the color, there is no option to set as default value.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer, keep in mind that "pure white", or a material that has a reflectancy of 100% is not a realistic one. Most "white" objects in the real world have a reflectancy (or albedo) of 70 to 80%, in case you are wondering why blender uses that as default.

Comment: Yup, I knew that. The color is somewhat irrelevant to my question, I just want to be able to define default values. Thank you for the response.

Comment: You need to create the shader through a custom scritp that sets the values, else you can modify the source code for blender.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98294/custom-default-settings-for-nodes-materials

Comment: Create a group with principled and set the inputs of the group with wanted default values (you'll only loose access to distribution and scattering).